# Как убрать активность из стека, после запуска другой

Tags: android, activity

У меня есть три активности.

1. `ActivityOne`.
2. `ActivityTwo` (с диалоговой темой).
3. `ActivityThree`.

`ActivityOne` вызывает `ActivityTwo`. После того, как `ActivityTwo` отработает, она вызывает `ActivityThree`.

Вызов происходит через

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, ActivityThree.class);
startIntent(i)
```

После того, как произошел вызов `ActivityThree`, мне необходимо закрыть `ActivityOne`. Я хотел передать ссылку на нее, при вызове `ActivityTwo`, чтобы ее закрыть, но мне написали, что так нельзя. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно подобрать флаги с которыми запускаются активити
например, если ActivityOne, ActivityTwo запускаются с флагом
`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`
(http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY),
то они не будут сохраняться в стеке.

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, ActivityThree.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startIntent(i);
```